# sql query to unify results length

Tags: c#, sql, string, t-sql

I'm trying to build a query to return some texts with same length..

Example :
select text from myTable : returns

```
abc > ( lets say this text length is 3 )
a   > 1
b   > 1
```

i want a query which returns

```
abc > 3
a   > 3
b   > 3
```

the idea is to have all text with same length ( i'm thinking of something which finishes text with some blank space to get a specific length )

so i can in my application have results with same height.. i need this to unify lengths and use the same amount of tabulations (tab) in my code for a well formated rtf document

Thank you in advance for reading

EDIT : SOLVED

I fixed my problem with these 4 lines

```
string c = rdr["text"].ToString();
                    int i = 30 - rdr["text"].ToString().Length;
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        c = c + " ";
```

Comment: You can cast it as a `Char` with the length you're wanting, or just handle it code-level.

Comment: IMHO, you should do stuff like this in the presentation layer, not in the database back-end.

Comment: Can you please give me an example..

Comment: Its not very clear what you are looking at doing.  If you are trying to make a one character string be 3 characters, you need to re-think your structure.  I'll second @500's comment

Comment: the thing is in backend... it'll consume lots of memory with too much conditions. i'm trying to create some rtf document and the library i'm using does not offer inserting text in a specific position.. so i'm trying to use tab character for moving text in each line... but text lenghts differ and that give bad formated document, thats why i'm thinking of handling this from the sql query

Comment: rtf markup text is not pretty.  Its markup text so that the document can be pretty.  Why do you need to insert markup text in a specific location?

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe selecting the max length is what you want?  like this:

```
select text, max(length(text)) as len
from myTable
```